# find threaded on Laravel like cakephp find method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We use `$this->Comment->find('threaded');` in CakePHP for fetch threaded rows.
Now I need to use like method in laravel for fetch threaded.
Please help me.

Comment: What is "threaded" ? Is it a type of Comment? Can you show us the table structure of your Comment table?

Comment: @RahulGupta No, it's something specific of cakePHP: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded

Comment: You should use `eloquent`, which is an ORM used by Laravel to deal with database searchs.